# Current amplifier for a PLC Analogue Output

Tags: current, circuit-design, plc

I am looking to amplify the 0-20mA (or -10V~+10V) analogue output from a Siemens PLC module (Siemens S7-1200 SM1232) into 0-165mA @ 24VDC proportional solenoid that continuously controls gas flow in a PID loop (SMC PVQ31-5G-16-01-F).  I measure 102 ohm across the unloaded solenoid coil.  Obviously a single 24VDC rail is available for power.

It's a relatively low power consumption, so a single 8.25x current gain stage would be a great solution if possible.

Can anyone point me towards a suitable schematic and ideally a suitable transistor?

Input 0-20mA (or -10V ~+10V)  //
Output 0-165mA @ 24VDC  //
0-24VDC Voltage Rail

https://sg.misumi-ec.com/vona2/detail/221300030360/

https://mall.industry.siemens.com/mall/en/ww/catalog/product/6es7232-4hd32-0xb0

Answer (score 1):

According to the Linear Tech [LT1010](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1010.pdf) and [LT1012](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT1012.pdf) datasheets, something like the following should be possible:

[image: 0-20mA to 0-165mA Converter Rev B]

Note that a -5V rail is needed to bias these for zero input to equal zero output.

Such a design should also be able to power cabling with significant capacitance at a decent slew rate without oscillating, thanks to the LT1010 unity-gain buffer.